# Finding characteristic function in the given question

Tags: real-analysis

If $f : A \to B$ and $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E \subset B$, of what subset of $A$ is the composition function $\chi_E \circ f$ the characteristic function?

Now my question is how should I determine it? No more information is given in the question.

Any hint or idea is welcomed.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to post your questions.

Comment: Extremly sorry, but I am new to. LATEX.

Answer (score 0):

$\chi_E \circ f$ is the characteristic function of $f^{-1}(E)$ the preimage of $E$ under $f$. How to proof that?

Suppose that $x \in f^{-1}(E)$, then $f(x) \in E$ and therefore $$(\chi_E \circ f)(x)=\chi_E(f(x))=1.$$ And conversely if $x \notin f^{-1}(E)$ you get $(\chi_E \circ f)(x)=0$.